# Advertising VXLAN learned MACs into a different namespace

Tags: networking, network-namespaces, netlink

I would like to run a l2 evpn (vxlan) bgp speaker in a different namespace and advertise the learned addresses into another namespace. In building the following topology, the BGP daemon populates the fdb table in the namespace it runs in, however addresses that then appear in the fdb table aren't advertised or discovered on the connected bridge. What am I fundamentally missing in this deployment?

[image: evpn fdb namespace extension]